# How to retrieve profile of my user details into profile page of user

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

**My view of user profile**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated, ))
def user_profile(request,id):
try:
    up = get_object_or_404(User_Profile, pk=id)
except User_Profile.DoesNotExist:
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
if request.method == 'GET':
    account=request.user
    post=Post.objects.all().filter(author=account)
    post_serializer=PostSerializer(post)
    follower_serializer = FollowerSerializer(up)
    following_serializer = FollowingSerializer(account)
    serializer=[follower_serializer.data,following_serializer.data,post_serializer.data]
    content = {
    'status': 1, 
    'responseCode' : status.HTTP_200_OK, 
    'data': serializer,
    }
    return Response(content)
```

When I run this it says:

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'author'

but when I run in shell without using serializer just using this code `post=Post.objects.all().filter(author=account)` it shows me the posts related to user. So what is problem with my serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, **`post`** is a *QuerySet*, so you should initialize the serializer with **`many=True`**

```
post_serializer=PostSerializer(post, many=True)
```

Comment: Thank you brother! It was such a minor mistake i even didn't think of that! :)